# Accidently Deleted all file names containing libboost under usr/lib and usr/include, now ubuntu doesn't start up

Tags: boot, data-recovery, startup

As the title says, did something really stupid. Now Ubuntu doesn't start. I can enter grub, recovery mode, and also enter the root menu. However, Ubuntu doesn't open normally. A black screen appears and it is stuck in there. I can access my files on the recovery mode root option.

Please, how can I recover my data also Ubuntu if possible?

Comment: Unless encrypted you can always easily recover data from a live session. Maybe be better to do just that and then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: but can I restore it with an easy way? Can I recover ubuntu with usb maybe?

Comment: I can't and shouldn't comment one way or another without knowing the full extent of the damage (this *isn't* a hint for you to post and entire description of what you did - you may if you want -, again, reinstalling is probably easier and much faster) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible way of recovery is the following:

1. boot the system in recovery mode
2. mount `/` as read-write

   ```
   mount / -o remount,rw
   ```
3. get IP address from DHCP server using `dhclient enp0s3` (you can get exact interface name from `ip a` or `ifconfig`)
4. reinstall all boost-related installed packages by

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -i boost | awk '{print $2}')
   apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S boost | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u)
   ```

   Note: if this last step does not help - change the command to the following -

   ```
   apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
   ```

   (here we reinstall all installed packages, as we do not know what was really removed)

Comment: So i need to be connected to internet?

Comment: Yes, of course. To access the repositories. With some luck some packages may exist in */var/cache/apt/archives*, but not all.

Comment: The thing is I cannot connect internet, I stated network manager, and ifconfig up, however when I wrote "ip a" interfaces does not get any ip

Comment: Try to adjust `dhclient enp0s3` for your ethernet wired interface with cable connected.

Comment: i took out my wifi ethernet, connected to pc, wrote your commad for my ethernet interface name, but nothing happens in first 10 seconda

Comment: Also dhclient + Tab, list the directory not the interfaces, interestingly.

Comment: You can try `nmtui` instead.

Comment: Nmtui worked, i will try the rest of the commands you told me

Comment: Nmtui + last command worked ty for your help

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the same approach as the answer of N0rbert, but we will only try to reinstall the libboost packages.

So if you get into recovery mode, enable your network and then drop to the root shell.

Then run `apt list --installed | grep libboost` to print all installed packages with libboost in their name. on my system the output would look like this (only a sample):

```
libboost-filesystem1.71.0/hirsute,now 1.71.0-6ubuntu11 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-filesystem1.74.0/hirsute,now 1.74.0-8ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-iostreams1.71.0/hirsute,now 1.71.0-6ubuntu11 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Thereafter run  `apt --reinstall install {packagename packagename ...}` , where packagename is everything until the first /.

Hope this helps